# Python Regex - Sentence not including strings

Tags: python, regex

I have a series of sentences I am trying to decipher. Here are two examples:

```
Valid for brunch on Saturdays and Sundays
```

and

```
Valid for brunch
```

I want to compose a regex that identifies the word brunch, but only in the case where the sentence does not include the word saturday or sunday. How can I modify the following regex to do this?

```
re.compile(r'\bbrunch\b',re.I)
```

Comment: Test them separately in 2 operations?

Comment: did you want to print only the word? I think you don't need a regex for this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^(?!.*saturday)(?!.*sunday).*(brunch)
```

You can try in this way.Grab the capture.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/nL5yL3/18

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html python regexes can only use fixed length lookbehinds.

Comment: @Jasper: this is a lookahead, not lookbehind.

Comment: @Jasper thanx a lot for the downvote and the reasoing behind it as well

Comment: How could this be adjusted to search within individual sentences. For example: It is valid on Saturdays. Valid for brunch. Good today and tomorrow. https://regex101.com/r/nL5yL3/34

Comment: @user2694306 ` It is valid on Saturdays. Valid for brunch. Good today and tomorrow.` will notbe selected as it has `saturday`.so that's right but you want to selec `valid for brunch`?

Comment: Exactly, so internally tokenizing the sentences to differentiate them.

Answer (score 1):

use a list comprehension , if you have all the sentences in a list like `sentences` you can use the following comprehension :

```
import re
[re.search(r'\bbranch\b',s) for s in sentences if `saturday` not in s and 'sunday' not in s ]
```

Comment: i think op wants to do a case insensitive match of saturday and sunday.

Comment: @AvinashRaj maybe , so we have to wait for his response ! ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would do like this,

```
>>> sent = ["Valid for brunch on Saturdays and Sundays", "Valid for brunch"]
>>> sent
['Valid for brunch on Saturdays and Sundays', 'Valid for brunch']
>>> for i in sent:
        if not re.search(r'(?i)(?:saturday|sunday)', i) and re.search(r'brunch', i):
            print(i)


Valid for brunch
```