# Python Regex - Different Results in findall and sub

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to replace occurrences of the work 'brunch' with 'BRUNCH'. I am using a regex which correctly identifies the occurrence, but when I try to use re.sub it is replacing more text than identified with re.findall. The regex that I am using is:

```
re.compile(r'(?:^|\.)(?![^.]*saturday)(?![^.]*sunday)(?![^.]*weekend)[^.]*(brunch)',re.IGNORECASE)
```

The string is

```
str = 'Valid only for dine-in January 2 - March 31, 2015. Excludes brunch, happy hour, holidays, and February 13 - 15, 2015.'
```

I want it to produce:

```
'Valid only for dine-in January 2 - March 31, 2015. Excludes BRUNCH, happy hour, holidays, and February 13 - 15, 2015.'
```

The steps:

```
>>> reg.findall(str)
>>> ['brunch']
>>> reg.sub('BRUNCH',str)
>>> Valid only for dine-in January 2 - March 31, 2015BRUNCH, happy hour, holidays, and February 13 - 15, 2015.
```

Edit:

The final solution that I used was:

```
re.compile(r'((?:^|\.))(?![^.]*saturday)(?![^.]*sunday)(?![^.]*weekend)([^.]*)(brunch)',re.IGNORECASE)
re.sub('\g<1>\g<2>BRUNCH',str)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `re.sub` use

```
(^|\.)(?![^.]*saturday)(?![^.]*sunday)(?![^.]*weekend)([^.]*)(brunch)
```

Replace by `\1\2BRUNCH`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/eZ0yP4/16

Comment: Only issue is that it deletes the period.

Comment: re.sub works better in this situation because its part of a list of regexes that normalizes text. Not all substitutions are so simple. Additionally, if there are multiple occurrences of the word but in different contexts, you would want to only replace the correct one.

Comment: @AvinashRaj the regex was asked by OP in his earlier questions.Please check it.There i had answered this.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27398870/python-regex-sentence-not-including-strings

Answer (score 2):

Through regex:

```
(^|\.)(?![^.]*saturday)(?![^.]*sunday)(?![^.]*weekend)([^.]*)brunch
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/eZ0yP4/15)

Replace the matched characters by `\1\2BRUNCH`

Answer (score 0):

**Why does it match more than `brunch`**

Because your regex actually does match more than brunch

[**See link on how the regex match**](https://regex101.com/r/wV3mP9/5)

**Why doesnt it show in `findall`?**

Because you have wraped only the `brunch` in paranthesis

```
>>> reg = re.compile(r'(?:^|\.)(?![^.]*saturday)(?![^.]*sunday)(?![^.]*weekend)[^.]*(brunch)',re.IGNORECASE)
>>> reg.findall(str)
['brunch']
```

After wraping  entire `([^.]*brunch)` in paranthesis

```
>>> reg = re.compile(r'(?:^|\.)(?![^.]*saturday)(?![^.]*sunday)(?![^.]*weekend)([^.]*brunch)',re.IGNORECASE)
>>> reg.findall(str)
[' Excludes brunch']
```

- `re.findall` ignores those are not caputred